# Solr: How to get count of distinct elements

Tags: solr

I'm trying to get total count of distinct elements irrespective of number of rows(length).

I used `group=true&group.field=filedName` on Solr Admin Console, though it groups the items it doesn't give total count .
To explain better in screenshot i'm expecting total count as 5 not 38.
(something like select count in sql)[Example-Solr-Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66wm2.png)

Answer (score 2):

Use [the `unique` facet function](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_7/json-facet-api.html#metrics-example):

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/collection/query -d '
q=...&
fq=...&
json.facet={
  "skus_count" : "unique(skuNumbers)",
}'
```